# How to compare two arrays and remove matching elements from one array in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have two arrays.

```
let array1 = ["Lahari", "Vijayasri"];
let array2 = ["Lahari", "Vijayasri", "Ramya", "Keerthi"];
```

I want to remove the array1 elements in array2 and print the final array-like

```
result array = ["Ramya", "Keerthi"]
```

Comment: Is order of the output array important?  Is `array1` guaranteed to be in the same order as `array2` and only contain elements that are in `array2`?

Comment: For clarification, what should the result be if `array1` is `["Vijayasri", "Lahari", "Vijayasri"]` and `array2` is `["Lahari", "Vijayasri", "Ramya", "Keerthi", "Lahari"]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting the arrays to `Set`s and using `subtract` is a simple and efficient method:

```
let array1 = ["Lahari", "Vijayasri"]
let array2 = ["Lahari", "Vijayasri", "Ramya", "Keerthi"]

let resultArray = Array(Set(array2).subtracting(Set(array1)))
```

If maintaining the order of `array2` is important then you can use `filter` with a set -

```
let compareSet = Set(array1)

let resultArray = array2.filter { !compareSet.contains($0) }
```

Comment: That doesn't preserve order.

Comment: Preserving order wasn't a stated requirement

Comment: I guess that depends on your interpretation of "like"! 

Comment: Well, I am sorry and delete my comment ;)

Answer (score 3):

`Paulw11` answer works perfectly. But if ordering in array is important you can do this:

```swift
let reuslt = array2.filter { !array1.contains($0) }
```

Comment: It is worth noting that this does preserve order, but at the cost of being O(n^2)

Comment: using Set has a better performance but in this way, ordering is the main goal

Answer (score 2):

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func difference(from other: [Element]) -> [Element] {
        let thisSet = Set(self)
        let otherSet = Set(other)
        return Array(thisSet.subtracting(otherSet))
    }
}

var array1 = ["Lahari", "Vijayasri"]
let array2 = ["Lahari", "Vijayasri", "Ramya", "Keerthi"]
let a = array2.difference(from: array1) // ["Ramya", "Keerthi"]
```